# Which is this graph library?

Tags: android, graph

Anyone knows which graph library use this application? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.systemmonitor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks a lot similar to this https://bitbucket.org/danielnadeau/holographlibrary/wiki/Home 
hope it help

Comment: Yeah it's very similiar but i don't know how use it :(. I have to create a battery chart. You know how do it?

Comment: Check the source it has an example of how to use it